# Changing background color based on function output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a function called shift_color, long story short it gives me a different color code(out putting "#FF5F74", "#5FFF66", "#5F8AFF")

and i want to use this output to style a nav menu background.

I tried:

```
.topnav {
background-color: <?php echo shift_color(); ?>;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

and a few other poor attempts i wont mention here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with you create an array containing values from 0 - 366 with a step of 3. So your array values will be 0, 3, 6, 9 etc. All of these days will be day 1 of the rota

```
$days = range(0,366,3);
```

Then find out which day of the year today is and assign it to a variable

```
$day = date("z");
```

Now check if the value for today is in the array, if it is then it's day 1. If not then we can see if it's day 2 by adding 2 to todays day number and seeing if that's a day 1 on the rota. If that doesn't match then it must be day 3, but we'll double check by adding 1 to the day number and seeing if that would be a day 1

```
switch (true) {
    case (in_array($day, $days)):
    $shiftColor = '#FF5F74';   // Set your css classes or whatever here
    break;
    case (in_array(($day + 2), $days)):
    $shiftColor = '#5FFF66';  //  and here
    break;
    case (in_array(($day + 1), $days)):
    $shiftColor = '#5F8AFF';  //and here
    break;
}
```

Then below this you put your css

```
.topnav {
background-color: <?php echo $shiftColor; ?>;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: So, if i Have a function that works currently to do this, and i want that background color value to become the value this function outputs, how do i use this in that particular .div style?

Comment: Updated my answe with an example

Comment: You're a saint,

followups, how do i set todays date into your function i keep getting an error.

when i hit a leap year in the future do i have to revisit this and change orders?

Comment: You don't need to set todays date `$day = date("z");` will return the number for the day of the year (349/350 depending on your timezone). It will still work on a leap year. You just need to figure out which day of the rota falls on which day of the year. Day 349 is day 2 in my code, which is Sat 16th Dec.

Comment: This is so much cleaner than what we had, which i couldnt get working anyway. Can you set a time of day that this change takes effect specifically 0800?

Comment: Sure. After this `$day = date("z");` just put `if(date("H") < 9) {$day -= 1;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to read user's current date and time and provide different content accordingly. 
Of course you can use the whatever server side technology you are using to achieve this, php, python, java...

For some tasks you may want to use the cron job.

Run
    crontab -e
On your server's command line to open in an editor. And add

```
0 8 * * * /your script path to change an item
0 0 * * 1 /your script to change background color for Monday
0 0 * * 2 /your script for Tuesday
0 0 * * 3 /your script for Wednesday
```

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding correctly you have 3 types of shifts (let's say A, B, C) and there is always one of this shifts active. You want the website background-color to reflect the active shift.

you will have to create some sort of server side application to handle that. If you rely on the client-side you will have issues regarding their time-zone etc.

You can also just schedule a script task on your server that changes the color to the next one every day at 8:00 server-time.

Comment: Okay, its all internal, cant be accessed outside of the department so i imagine that wouldn't be a problem.

any idea where i can start reading?